# Cannot Simulate Liquid/Fire/Smoke, and I have tried seemingly everything

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I cannot get any smoke/fire/liquid to simulate.

Current Version is 2.90

At this point I am almost willing to pay someone to fix this problem because I have tried everything, from following tutorials step by step, as well as searching on sites like these and no fixes at all for me.

I even tried completely deleting and redownloading/installing blender and this also did not work. I have tried both evee and cycles

Could someone possibly provide me a simple file that I can open and try to see if that works? Is there any specific settings, or preferences or addons that I might be missing?

I appreciate any/all help you can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello :). How far have you got so far and what tutorials have you followed?

Comment: I have tried at least 15 or more tutorials for smoke and liquid, and I have not been able to get either to work at all, ever. I even try to find the most recent tutorial, hoping I'll find a little trick for a newer version but still nothing.